# Passing text to variable in KSH. Not Working

Tags: unix, awk, ksh

Hi I am struggling to solve this simple program. I am not able to pass the value from the text file to the variable. 
I am stuck at this: `value=$( sed -n "${line}p" rpt1.txt|awk {$3}`

O/P:

```
1.sh[15]: test: argument expected
```

CODE:

```
wc `find /arbor/custom/gur/fold1`|grep -vi "total"| tee rpt1.txt
total1=`wc -l rpt1.txt`
wc `find /arbor/custom/gur/fold2`|grep -vi "total"| tee rpt2.txt
total2=`wc -l rpt2.txt`
line=1
if [ $line  -le  $total1 ]
then
value=$( sed -n "${line}p" rpt1.txt|awk {$3} )
if [ $value  -eq  512 ];
then
sed -n "${line}p" rpt1.txt|awk '{print $4}'| tee direc.txt
fi
line =$line+1
else
echo "loop over"
fi
```

Comment: Your code isn't very readable.  I have a feeling there are things that are being interpreted as markup by stackoverflow which is making it difficult to tell what might be a problem, and what isn't.  Anyway, my guess is that you're missing quotes around your awk program.

Comment: @Eric is right, you need `awk '{ $3 }'`.

Comment: @Eric Thanks a lot. Squiguy your suggestion worked!

Comment: You also want `let line++` instead of the broken `line =$line+1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't there be a print in front of $3 in the suspect line?